# Difference between 'floor' and 'level'

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english

If my home address is; plot #120, 4th floor, Road #5, Dhanmondi.  Can I write my address as:

> plot #120, *level* #5, Road #5, Dhanmondi.

Note that instead of writing *4th floor*, I used *Level #5*.

**Question**:

- Is the different numbering between *floor* and *level* correct?

Comment: the key point is that the **difference between numbering** in US V. UK (whether you start at zero or one), **IS NOT CONNECTED TO** the various words you can use.  there is literally **absolutely no difference** between the words "level" and "floor" in either region.  Absolutely no difference, they are 100% interchangeable at all times.  If you are saying second floor, you can also say second level.  No difference at all.

Comment: @JoeBlow Since Kamal is in Bangladesh, I don't think the US vs. UK difference is that relevant to him. More importantly, though, _level_ and _floor_ are not the interchangeable, at least not to me. An office may be on the fourth floor or level four (or, I guess, the fourth level, though that sounds strange) of an office building; but while I live on the second floor or storey, I certainly don't live on level two in my apartment building. _Level_ is not in my experience used for residence, except if we're talking ship cabins or something like that.

Comment: Hmm, in France, for example, a "left hand drive" is called an "English", although also in say Japan cars are like that. I simply meant "0-numbering" or "1-numbering" style.

Comment: regarding level etc.   Sure, there are some extremely subtle differences. For example (in some areas) you tend to describe car parking structures using more "level" than "floor" wouldn't you agree?  Re: "residential, level" as you say, I agree, but indeed in high rise culture (say in HK) it seems common to me to ask what level you're on, etc.  The simple fact is  **THERE IS NO DIFFERENCE** between the two - that's a fact.  Sure, you might sound a bit "ESL" if you use the slightly wrong one in some context. But that's true of, well, anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think the level number is the same as the floor number:

> - A ***storey*** (Australian English, British English, Canadian English, Indian English, New Zealand English) or ***story*** (American English) ***is any level part of a building that could be used by people*** (for living, work, storage, recreation, etc.). The plurals are "storeys" and "stories" respectively.
> - ***The terms floor, level or deck can also be used in this sense; except that one may use "ground floor" and "ground level" for the floor closer to what is considered the ground or street level***.The words "storey" and "floor" also generally exclude levels of the building that have no roof, even if they are used by people—such as the terrace on the top roof of many buildings. ([Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey))

Comment: Interestingly, I'm fairly sure that Americans start numbering floors with floor (/level/storey) 1 being the ground floor, whereas Brits and Australians make floor 1 the floor above ground floor.

Comment: Yes, true: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69841/ground-floor-vs-first-floor

Answer (score 0):

I think it can vary depending whether the building is on a hillside.  I work in a building (in California) that has 3 floors. The "Ground" floor is entered from the back of the building, which is lower than the street side. The 2nd floor is entered from the street side, but is at least 8' below street level; one has to go down a ramp, or a dozen steps, to get to the 2nd floor entry. The 3rd floor starts about 6' above street level. You could say that the Ground Floor is a *daylight basement*, but there is a basement below it, which is a parking garage.  So the elevator buttons are **P, G, 2, and 3.**