# Ground Floor versus First Floor; Who is Less Wrong?

Tags: american-english, british-english

In the UK we say 'ground floor' and in the US they say 'first floor' for the lowest level in a building.

As I am fairly sure, no-one else in the world uses this terminology.

Does this make Britons wrong, or illogical?

I ask because while trying to explain to my European friend that the ground floor is on the ground, it came to me that our first floor would be the second [peice of flooring] that you would walk upon, thus making it the second floor.

I'm stumped.

EDIT: I feel like this question should be in civil engineering, not language, do say if I'm ok or not.

Comment: This has already been asked here, although the premise that the British are either wrong or illogical is not so much the focus:

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238495/first-floor-vs-ground-floor-usage-origin

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69841/ground-floor-vs-first-floor

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Ground floor" vs. "first floor"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69841/ground-floor-vs-first-floor)

Comment: *Ground floor* ***is*** also used in the US. It's just that in the US, both *ground floor* and *first floor* refer to the ***same*** floor—the one at ground level. In the UK, however, the *first floor* is the *first floor **above** ground level*.

Answer (score 2):

No.

On your specific light-hearted question as to the "wrongness and illogicality" of the British usage, according to one of the resources [in the answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/238506/324870) to the linked duplicate/related questions, it appears to be a reasonable split with that terminology used across Europe, Australasia and India.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storey#Numbering

So, your premise here is incorrect; the usage is neither wrong or illogical, and is shared widely across the world. Qualification: The cited evidence for that passage 404s.

btw. Note that at the time of writing, the column headings in that table could be argued as biased towards a particular viewpoint: "Height relative to ground (storeys)" naturally inclines to the American usage of "floor".